# How to remove '\n' from the values of my dictionary

Tags: python

I have a text file containing

```
EcoRI;G^AATTC
BamHI;G^GATCC
PstI;CTGCA^G
AluI;AG^CT
```

after putting them into a dictionary and printing the dictionary I get `{'EcoRI': 'G^AATTC\n', 'BamHI': 'G^GATCC\n', 'PstI': 'CTGCA^G\n', 'AluI': 'AG^CT\n'}` as an output. what are those '\n' at the end of each value ? How can I remove them?

I used this code to put them into dictionary

```
 my_file_2 = open('enzymes.txt', 'r')
    dic_enz = {}
    for line in my_file_2:
        key, value = line.split(';')
        dic_enz[key] = value
    print(dic_enz)
    my_file_2.close()
```

Comment: `\n` stands for new-line. Use `line.strip().split(';')` to remove it

Comment: before putting each string in dictionary, call `strip` function on each string

Comment: `'\n'` means newline, and it's only one character - so you can clip it with slicing: `key = key[:-1]`. `'\n'` gets in your value because that's the end of line and `readline` (which is used when you iterate with `for`) also returns the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open (file)
lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is is what gets typed when you press the "enter" key on your keyboard. Otherwise, how does the computer know to put the next line of a text on a seperate line? `\n` is known as the "new-line" character. another similar character is `\r`, named "carriage-return". This hearkens back to the days of typewriters and also when computer console output was printed out on paper. They are still used today to indicate that text should go on the next line, instead of continuing on the same line.

```
aaaaaabbbbbbbb
```

versus

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb
```

You can remove these using `strip`. For example,

x = "\n   banana\n\n\r".strip()
   print(x) # prints "banana"

`strip` will also remove all space characters (), tab ("`\t`"), etc... from the beginning and end of the text.

I have edited your original code:

```
 my_file_2 = open('enzymes.txt', 'r')
    dic_enz = {}
    for line in my_file_2:
        key, value = line.split(';')
        key = key.strip()
        value = value.strip()
        dic_enz[key] = value
    print(dic_enz)
    my_file_2.close()
```